# Some question on Lovett-Meka Discrepancy Minimisation Algorithm

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, discrepancy-theory

I am reading the paper [Constructive Discrepancy Minimization by Walking on The Edges](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.5747.pdf)
 which finds the discrepancy of a set system matching [Spencer's bound](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2000258), in randomised polynomial time. In short, given vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with unit $l_2$ norm, and a starting vector $x_0 \in K:=[-1,1]^n$, define the polytope

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \vert\langle x-x_0,v_j\rangle\vert\leq c_j\forall j\in[m]\}
\end{align}
Then if the following condition is met
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^m \exp(-c_j^2/16) \leq \frac{n}{16}
\end{align}
, then in randomized polynomial time one can fine a point $x\in \mathcal{P}\cap K$, such that at least half the coordinates are in $\{-1,1\}$ (or very close to it).

My first question is that

1. What is the volume of $\mathcal{P}\cap K$. The motivation is that: the "edge walk" algorithm computes a sequence of vectors that stay within this polytope. Perhaps one can proof this if one can show that the volume is large.
2. In step $t$ of the algorithm, the algorithm takes a "random" step in certain orthogonal subspace $\mathcal{V}_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (using the notation from the aforementioned paper). The random step is chosen first by choosing an orthogonal basis of $\mathcal{V}_t$, and then pick a standard Gaussian random variable for each coordinate. Are there any other nice probability distribution that can be used in place of such "projected Gaussian vector". Perhaps a uniform vector from $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\cap\mathcal{V}_t$. I think the answer should be "yes", because a normalised Gaussian vector is uniformly distributed over $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.